# How to store and manage users with IdentityServer?

Tags: identityserver4

I am currently looking into how to store and manage users in a production IdentityServer solution.

My question is how do you store and manage your users with IdentityServer? What have you tried that worked? and what to avoid?

- Do you roll your own solution?
- Use ASP.NET Identity?

I did read about the AdminUI commercial project, any alternatives? Any good publicly free available open-source solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you roll your own solution?
> Use ASP.NET Identity?

I personally prefer ASP.NET Identity

- There is a lot of examples and a quick-start available (i.e. [IDS4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html), [An old but good blog](https://damienbod.com/2016/11/18/extending-identity-in-identityserver4-to-manage-users-in-asp-net-core/))
- You have a very good, well documented and extensible base framework, classes and types already in-place and you can build on the top of it

Also as a side note, I would say keep IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Identity solutions separated to have two separate development and deployment lifecycles, separate teams, etc.

> I did read about the AdminUI commercial project, any alternatives? Any good publicly free available open-source solutions?

There is a nice open source admin UI available from [skoruba](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/blob/master/README.md). You can find more docs [here](https://skoruba-identityserver4-admin.readthedocs.io/en/dev-doc/index.html)